# Prevent a user from running multiple instances of Air application

Tags: air

How can i prevent a user from running multiple instances of Air application?
somebody help me.. plz.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for a user to run more than one instance of an AIR application so you are already done!

Comment: I appreciate for your help. but still i have not found out a correct answer what i want.

Comment: for examples, Tweetdeck that is developed with adobe air is always running one instance.

Comment: The AIR launcher checks against the Application ID before starting the application. If an instance with that ID is currently running, it will not launch another instance. So you do not need to guarantee that; the runtime does that for you.